# What are the functions $\Re,\Im$?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, notation

I saw in LaTeX that typing `\Re` gives '$\Re$', and typing `\Im` gives '$\Im$', and when I searched online, I found that "\Re is the LaTeX symbol for the real function $\Re$." on some website, so I assume that the same is true for \Im for "the complex function $\Im$".

But what are those functions? Are they the functions $\text{Re}(\>)$ and $\text{Im}(\>)$ defined on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The real part and the imaginary part.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I've never seen that notation before.

I'm adding your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on DHMO's comment above:

They are notations for the same things:

$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}:$
$\text{Re}(z) \equiv \Re (z)$, the real part of $z$, $\text{Im}(z) \equiv \Im (z)$, the imaginary part of $z$

Comment: You can close the question by accepting your own answer.

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot about it. Thanks for telling me that. :)

Edit: I can do it only from 2 days from now.

Comment: I sonder about the relative popularity of $\text{Re}(z)$ and $\Re (z)$ nowadays.  I guess $\Re (z)$ was used in the 19th century.  But what about today?  Is there a recent textbook in complex analysis that uses $\Re (z)$ ??  Would it be completely forgotten today if Knuth hadn't put in in the original TeX?