# Can ℜ be used instead of ℝ to represent a real coordinate space? If not, what alternatives are commonly used?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

When going through logistic regression I was writing some documentation using classic `troff` and `eqn` UNIX tools.

In logistic regression, it is common to find explanations that match the input to a vector that belongs to a real coordinate space of dimension n, that can be written ${R} ^{n}$ or $\mathbb {R} ^{n}$ as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_coordinate_space).

Now, in `troff` and `eqn` you can use ℜ (see [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff_char.7.html) for a list of valid symbols) but not ℝ.

I have two questions:

1. Would symbol ℜ be a valid representation or does it mean a different thing?
2. If not, and given that symbol ℝ is not available, what could be used as alternative?

Note: I do not have a formal background in mathematics, if something in the question is not accurate please feel free to edit.

Comment: I believe that's the real-part operator from complex analysis: $\Re[a + bi] = a.$ In which case these are not the same thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the functions $\Re,\Im$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233699/what-are-the-functions-re-im)

Comment: When a "blackboard bold" $\mathbb R$ is unavailable for the real numbers, sometimes one would use regular bold, as in $\mathbf R$.

Comment: Thanks Mark S. The post that you link would answer question 1, which would be: *no, ℜ is not a valid representation*, but it would not answer question 2.
That one might be solved by your suggestion of using bold R. I will keep the question open to see if somebody provides other alternatives to bold R.

Comment: Just to be sure that you're asking the right question, is there a particular reason that this **must** be done in troff? Or is it possible that [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527873/69573) might apply?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David K. I am well aware of the existence of LaTeX and TeX and I have used them in the past.  I do not want to use them because they are overkilling for these particular tasks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you explain your notation, you can use *any* symbol you like. However, as $\mathfrak{R}$ is sometimes used for the real part of a complex number or other notions in mathematics, you should be aware that people who "scan" through your documentation may get confused.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for commonly used notations for this particular area.  Mark S. suggests above to use bold R. I am wondering if there might be others.

Comment: Italic $R$ could be an alternative